# How to run a batch file from Jenkins

Tags: batch-file, jenkins, cmd

I am trying to run a batch file from Jenkins but I can't get it to run.
In the pre-build step I have entered the file I want to execute but I get the stacktrace shown below. Jenkins doesn't recognize the cmd command.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Your Linux Jenkins slave doesn't support cmd**. In order to workaround it you have several options (from better to worse):

1. Add a Windows slave to Jenkins and run cmd from there.
2. Port your batch file to bash or similar and run it from your Linux Jenkins slave.
3. Add some kind of DOS emulator (Wine, DOSBox, DOSemu) in your Linux Jenkins slave.

**My advice**: If you know Linux & Bash or you have no control of Jenkins **go for option 2**. Otherwise go for option 1. Avoid option 3.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to run CMD on a LINUX machine. either change the slave you're running to Windows machine or migrate the Batch script to shell script.

Good luck!